# how to automaticly validate a web form?

Tags: php, curl, autofill

I found this code on stackoverflow, code of https://stackoverflow.com/users/370876/peter-anselmo

```
$url = 'http://www.targeturl.com';
$myvars = 'myvar1=' . $myvar1 . '&myvar2=' . $myvar2;

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

I want to fill two fields, one line is ok or two are needed (with curl)
and how can I make like an "if" to test if the url returned is what I want or no and re-try again (like a loop).
I know I ask

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you mean by your question, I'm sort of confused, but are you asking for something like this?

```
$foundURL = FALSE;
while(!$foundURL)
{
     // Make CURL request
     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     if ($respons == "the url I want") $foundURL = TRUE;
     // Load next http/url for curl request...
}
```

This loop will continue to execute and make CURL requests until the response matches some URL that you're searching for ...